# Postgresql: INSERT INTO many values from an excel column

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql, sql-insert

I need to  INSERT INTO many values from an excel column.

For example, I could do manually this:

```
INSERT INTO estructura.multiselect_options
(value, id_multiselect, type_multiselect)
VALUES 
('Some Value1', 9, 'field'), 
('Some Value2', 9, 'field'), 
('Some Other Value3', 9, 'field'), 
('Some Another Value4', 9, 'field'), 
etc...
```

The only value that change will be the first, those 'Some ValueN'. The others two will always be the same. But I have all those 'Some ValueN' in an Excel column, like this:

```
A
Some Value 1
Some Value 2
Some Other Value 3
Some Another Value 3
etc...
```

So, is there a way that I can copypaste a column from excel, and then put all the value in my query? some online tool, whatever, I can't figure it how could I do it. The guy that will do these expect a single query text to run in on the SQL Querys of Postgres. I can't use other way to execute the query, so my only goal is to make that large query text, but how.

Comment: I finally pick the second answer as the correct one. I could do all the work just with concatenating the word, like this: http://i.imgur.com/EnyQdlC.png  much faster and easy. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools out there to help turn data into inserts, but I usually do it for myself in Excel. Suppose your data is in columns A to C as follows:

```
  |         A           | B |   C   |
--+---------------------+---+-------+
1 | Some Value1         | 9 | field | 
2 | Some Value2         | 9 | field | 
3 | Some Other Value3   | 9 | field | 
4 | Some Another Value4 | 9 | field | 
--+---------------------+---+-------+
```

Then in D1 enter the formula

```
=CONCATENATE("('" , A1 , "'," , B1 , ",'", C1, "')," )
```

Copy this down all the rows. You should now be able to paste this column of data into your code window after the `insert values` part, and will simply need to remove the comma from after the final set of values to be inserted.

Alternatively, if you only have column A and need to repeat the others:

```
=CONCATENATE("('" , A1 , "', 9, 'field'),")
```

As noted by @luisarcher, instead of using the `CONCATENATE` function, you can combine the "arguments" using the concatenation symbol `&`. Done that way, the second forumla would become:

```
= "('" & A1 & "', 9, 'field'),"
```

I go back and forth as to which approach I prefer. I also sometimes put the odd bits such as `"('"` into other cells, and reference those. It makes the final formula much easier to construct.

Comment: Formulas like these can be confusing to type, did you copy and paste or hand-type? They don't error for me (at least not when placed in D1 for the first example and anywhere but A1 for the second).

Comment: Sometimes I simplify the formula by adding the necessary quote marks and commas to be output into other cells and then reference those cells in the formula.

Comment: you can use the operator & instead of CONCATENATE. It is a lot simpler to read aftwerwards.

Comment: You can, and I often do (use `&`). Not sure which I find easier to read!

Comment: In the image it's hard to tell after the `"(` if you have `"` then `'` or the otherway around. It needs to be `'` then `"`. My version should be okay to copy and paste.

Comment: Or, perhaps in your locale, the `CONCATENATE` function goes by another name. If that's Spanish, it might be `CONCATENAR`.

Comment: I have to do it like this: =CONCATENAR("('";A1;"', 9, 'field'),") in my Excel version I have to use "; , thanks mate

Comment: Fab. Glad we got there.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [this](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) website, you can save the excel file as .csv and paste it here. It will give you a query with all the inserts.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm looking right now to http://csv2mysql.patrotsky.com/csv2sql.php I will chechk which one will solve my problem. I'll take you answer as the correct one later if your page works better.